# UTF - encoding java

Tags: java, utf-8

I want to do utf-8 encoding on this string "DÃ¼rrnerstrasse 1 Postfach 1463,D-8800 Ansbach" in JAVA to avoid the special characters.

can some one share the code here please?

```
String s = rs.getString("address");
byte [] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
String newString = new String(b,"UTF-8");
```

its still the same after converting

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: which do you mean? it's not clear whether you want to avoid special characters, so transliterate(ö to oe) or encode to UTF-8 (from ISO 8859-1 it seems)....

Comment: String add = rs.getString("address");
String value = new String(add.getBytes("UTF8"));
System.out.println(value);

Comment: you ca see the characters like "Ã¼" i want to encode those. Basically i want apply  utf-8 encoding for the strings

Comment: I need to translate not avoid. Sorry for the usage of wrong word

Answer (score 2):

Your String is already UTF-8, but encoded in ISO-8859-1:

```
                // D      ü      r    r    n    e    r    s    t    r    a   s    s    e
byte[] rawdata = {68, -61, -68, 114, 114, 110, 101, 114, 115, 116, 114, 97, 115, 115, 101};
                  // 0xC3, 0xBC = "ü" in UTF-8
String s = new String(rawdata, "ISO-8859-1");   // this is what your rs.getString() returns
System.out.println(s);
```

results in

```
DÃ¼rrnerstrasse
```

If you want to re-interpret / re-encode the String `s` as UTF-8, you need to retrieve the byte array using the proper source encoding and then recreate a String with UTF-8 destination encoding:

```
byte[] stream = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String s2 = new String(stream, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(s2);
```

results in

```
Dürrnerstrasse
```

On a side note, assumed that `rs` is a JDBC ResultSet, you should also consider to configure your Database client / driver properly - if your database already uses UTF-8, the driver should be able to return properly encoded strings so that you do not need to re-encode them in your application.

Comment: His database must contain the garbled characters literally. It doesn't matter what driver encoding you use as long as the character set includes the characters being encoded (otherwise you get `?`). It only has a performance impact.